# Boton de eliminar php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

buen día, estoy tratando de eliminar un registro de mi base de datos desde php, pero no se elimina, y tampoco me arroja ningún error, al presionar el botón lo único que hace es recargarse la pagina pero el registro sigue ahí, quisiera saber si tengo algún error de antemano gracias.

conexión a la base de datos:

```
<?php 
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "iedan");
if($db->connect_error){
    die('error de conexion' . $db->connect_error);
}
?>
```

tabla con el boton:

```
 <?php 
            $sql="SELECT ta.id_tarea, ta.titulo, ta.fecha_creacion, ta.id_curso, cu.nombre_curso, ma.nombre_materia
            from tareas as ta, cursos as cu, materias as ma
            where ta.id_curso = cu.id_curso 
            and ta.id_materia = ma.id_materia
            and ta.id_profesor = '".$_SESSION['id_estudiante']['id_estudiante']."'" ;
            $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql) or trigger_error($db->error);
            while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
           ?> 
          <tr>
            <div class="user-panel20">
            </div>
            <a href="detallesTarea.php?id_tarea=<?php echo $mostrar ['id_tarea']; ?>">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">&nbsp;Detalles&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
            </a>
            <a href="EliminarTarea.php?id=<?php echo $mostrar ['id_tarea']; ?>">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">&nbsp;Eliminar&nbsp;&nbsp;</button>
            </a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <?php } ?>

      </tbody>
```

código para eliminar el registro:

```
<?php
include '../modelo/ConMod.php';
$id = $_POST["id_tarea"];
$query = "DELETE FROM tareas WHERE id_tarea = '$id'";
$result=mysqli_query($db,$query) or trigger_error($db->error);
if ($db->query($query) === TRUE) {
header("Location: consultarTarea.php");
 }
 else {
echo'<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("El id ya existe");
    window.location.href="paila.php";
    </script>';
   }
 mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: Lo que ocurre es que tu botón no tiene ninguna acción asociada, lo que te recomiendo es que a tu `<a>` le des estilo de botón para lograr lo que necesitas, algo asi: `<a href="EliminarTarea.php?id=<?php echo $mostrar['id_tarea']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Eliminar</a>`

Comment: Me parece que estas tomando un POST equivocado, debería sera solo $_POST["id"], para eliminarTarea

Comment: También tiene razón @EliasCatalan en el `$_POST` lo estas recibiendo con un nombre incorrecto. Saludos.

Comment: puse solo  $_POST["id"] y continua igual

Comment: @JosueArriola da lo mismo, lo cambie y sigue igual.

Comment: Saludos. Ademas de lo que ya te comentaron respecto a que es `id`y no `id_tarea` en el tag `<a>` lo envias por **get**; es decir, debe ser `$_GET["id"]` en vez de `$_POST["id_tarea"];` como de momento lo tienes.

Comment: @RobertoLeOr eso era, mil gracias.

Comment: @SergiioRodriguez También veo que en `$sql` has colocado  `$_SESSION['id_estudiante']['id_estudiante']` y debería ser `$_SESSION['id_estudiante']`

Comment: @JosueArriola si no dejo los dos no me funciona, aun así gracias.

Comment: Veo un código demasiado enrevesado, pero bueno ese es otro asunto. Ya los compañeros han indicado algunas cosas, pero, pregunto: ¿qué hace tu código actualmente? ¿redirige con el `Location` o muestra la alerta del `else`? Es que ese punto no queda claro.

Comment: en caso de que se realice bien la consulta redirige, en caso de que no muestra el aviso por medio del script y me redirige a otra pagina que muestra el error